# What kind of intra-particle interactions give rise to heat diffusion in a gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I want to consider an $N$ particle gas in a box initialized so that $k < N$ particles have some velocity magnitude $v_\mathrm{hot}$, and the remaining $N-k$ particle have velocities distributed (e.g. Gaussian distribution) around the magnitude $v_\mathrm{cold}$. Assume all the particles have the same mass. At equilibrium I expect the total kinetic energy to be distributed among all of the $N$ particles so that their velocities form a distribution  centered around $v_\mathrm{eq}=\sqrt{\frac{kv_\mathrm{hot}^2+(N-k)v_\mathrm{cold}^2}{N}}$ (because the average KE is $KE_{avg} = \frac{kKE_\mathrm{hot}+(N-k)KE_\mathrm{cold}}{N}$).

However, modeling collisions between the particles as elastic clearly does not lead to this dispersion of kinetic energy because the velocities between colliding particles are swapped, so at any given moment there will always be $k$ particles with velocity $v_\mathrm{hot}$ and their KE never spreads out. What would be a reasonable and realistic way to model collisions between gas particles s.t. the gas exhibits heat diffusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocities are only swapped in the case of a head-on collision. The chances of a single collision being head-on would be small-enough, and the chances of all the collisions being head-on for a large number of particles would be virtually zero, so a model that assumed the velocity was always swapped would be utterly unrealistic. You need simply to assume that the collisions are not head-on, but randomly oriented.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I should have thought of that. The two dimensional case is handled in this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects